# How to find appropriate functions for PureScript?

Tags: purescript

PureScript have lots of functions available like filter lenth and more. But how can we find the function that we need and its examples with implementation? I am facing problem solving exercises of the book purescript by examples. Any tips how show I go about solving those? Example in the book does not explain everythin.

Comment: You can use https://pursuit.purescript.org to search for functions.

Answer (score 1):

Really, the most straightforward way would be to use the tooling that comes with the compiler through an editor plugin. You can use `?typehole` to get the type of the type hole and get search results for relevant functions.

I also quite often type in a partial identifier and use the completion to look through the implementations, e.g. `fil <complete` to find various `filter` definitions.

Answer (score 1):

For all newbie to PureScript who are following PureScript by example book this github link has all the solutions with updated libraries
https://github.com/kvsm/purescript-by-example